# Open Atrium: How to add an action button on a view node

Tags: 7, distributions

I can add a button on the node edit form using a `hook_form_alter` and adding a new element to `$form['actions']`.

However, I would also like to add a button to the node view, next to `+ Create`. I assume there's an api for this but I can't seem to find it in the code or in documentation.

[image: Create action]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First, some terminology: the links in the dropdown menu on the bottom right are called `Contextual Tabs`. Second, the buttons with an icon are called `Extracted Tabs`. These settings are found in two different locations.

First, make your menu item a regular context tab. Go to `admin/openatrium/setting` and open the `Contextual Tabs` fieldset. Fill in the link to your page/menu item:

[image: OA1]

Next, extract the Contextual Tab as a button. Go to `admin/config/user-interface/contextual-tabs` and fill in the link and/or the label to your page/menu item in the `Tabs to extract` textarea:

[image: OA2]

Your link will now be displayed as a button with an icon of your liking.